# What are the numbers of vertices, edges, and faces in this polyhedron formed by the union of two $n$-gonal pyramids?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

> Assume that $\Delta \subset \Bbb{R}^3$ is a union $\Delta = \Delta_1 \cup \Delta_2$, where $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ are pyramids
> with the vertices $O_1 = (0,0,1)$ and $O_2 = (0,0,−1)$, respectively, over the same convex $n$-gon belonging to the coordinate plane $z = 0$. Find $V$, $E$, and $F$ (the numbers of vertices, edges, and faces) for this polyhedra.

From my understanding, the number of vertices in the figure should be $n+2$, where $n$ is the $n$-gon base of the two pyramids. The edges should then be $3n$, and the faces should be $2n$.

I tried to find the exact value of $n$ by using the $V-E+F=2$ formula but it all cancelled out to give $2=2$. Does this mean $n$ could be any $n$-gon, or is their a specific number for $n$ that I don't seem to get?

Comment: *"Does this mean n could be any n-gon [...]?"* Yes.

Comment: This seems to be a straightforward exercise in counting elements of a described polyhedron. Your calculations are correct. The fact that $V-E+F=2$ holds is a nice sanity check. (Of course, that check isn't a *guarantee*. It's possible to make multiple errors that cancel themselves out during the check.) It may also be that the exercise is meant to provide additional evidence for believing that $V-E+F=2$ *should* hold.